# Data da máscara altera após dar reload na página

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, data, tabela-html

Fiz uma máscara pelo PHP pra mudar o formato que a data aparece (para o padrão dd/mm/yyyy), aonde ao adicionar um novo registro, ele mostra a data corretamente. Porém, ao atualizar a página ele volta pra um formato fixo (01/01/1970).

PHP das variáveis das datas

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include('../_comum/config.php');


  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $idContrato = $_POST['idContrato'];
  $numContrato = $_POST['numContrato'];
  $dataInicio = $_POST['dataInicio'];
  $dataFinal = $_POST['dataFinal'];
  $responsavel = $_POST['responsavel'];
  $nomeCliFor = $_POST['nomeCliFor'];
  $ativo = isset($_POST['ativo']) ? 1 : 0;



  

  $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO Contrato(idContrato,numContrato,dataInicio,dataFinal,responsavel,ativo) VALUES('$idContrato', '$numContrato', '$dataInicio', '$dataFinal', '$responsavel','$ativo')");
    
  }
  header('contrato.php');
```

Lista dos Resgistros:

```
<div id='listaRegistros'>
  
  
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
             
              <th>Data Inicio</th>
              <th>Data Final</th>
             
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php

          while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataInicio))."</td>";
            echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataFinal))."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Formulário:

```
   
      <form action="contrato.php" id='cadastroRegistro' method = "POST">
      
      <div class="form-row" >
        
        <div class="col-1">
          <div>Numero do Contrato:</div>
            <div>
              <input type='text' id='' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="8" name = 'numContrato'/>
            </div>
        </div>    
          
            
          <div class="label">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div>Data Inicio:</div>
                <input type="date" id="birthday" name="dataInicio">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div>Data Término:</div>
                <input type="date" id="birthday" name="dataFinal">
              </div>
              
            <div class="col-1">
              <div>Responsável:</div>
                <input type="text" id='' data-ls-module="charCounter" maxlength="30" name = 'responsavel'/>
            </div>
              
            <div class="form-check form-switch col-1">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" name= 'ativo' value="on">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Ativo:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
            <button class="btnSalvar" type = "submit" name="submit">Salvar</button>
            <a href="contrato.php"><button class="btnSalvar" type = "button" formnovalidate>Voltar</button> </a>
          </div>
    </div>
      </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: você já verificou se essas informações estão sendo ( persistidas ) salvas no banco? Geralmente essa data padrão do mysql `01/01/1970` é exibida quando é feita a tentativa de inserção de uma data inválida

Comment: é muito provável que você esteja passando a data com um formato inválido no banco. Já tentou formatar no padrão `YYYY-DD-MM` ao salvar dentro do banco?

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca seu código por completo ( tanto a parte de formulário html , quando o resto do código em php ). Apenas com esse trecho parece que você ao dar o `refresh` na página estar salvando as datas como nulas, que pode estar vinculado com o seu problema.

Comment: @William no banco esta salvando tudo certinho, até quando eu edito ele altera de forma correta

Comment: @William coloquei o form certinho, junto com o código do insert do php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bom achei a solução. O erro estava propriamente na máscara do PHP. Sem a variavél `$user_data`, ao dar o reload a informação não era carregada.

```
echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user_data['dataInicio']))."</td>";
echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user_data['dataFinal']))."</td>";
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).